# Apache does not follow symlinks on Windows 403 forbidden

Tags: windows, apache-http-server, symbolic-link

I found many similar questions but only for Linux and they did not solve my problem. What I do is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80 *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName coreshop_demo.local

        DocumentRoot "D:/creation/software developer/projects/2021-coreshop-payment/web"
        <Directory />
                Options Indexes FollowSymlinks MultiViews
                Require all granted
                AllowOverride all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog logs/coreshop_demo.local/error.log
        CustomLog logs/coreshop_demo.local/access.log combined
        LogLevel warn
        
        AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
        AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html
        
        php_value display_errors "Off"
        php_value display_startup_errors "Off"
        php_value log_errors "On"
        
</Virtualhost>
```

I make my symlinks with something like `D:\creation\software developer\projects\2021-coreshop-payment\web\bundles> mklink /D "pimcorecore" "../../vendor/pimcore/pimcore/bundles/CoreBundle/Resources/public/`, so the `../../vendor` is not in the `web` directory.

When I try to access the files I got `403 forbidden` with PHP error log something like `invalid file or directory path syntax` with Apache error code: `AH00127`.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem that the `vendor` directory is not inside the document root and there is some sort of bug inside Apache, which does not allow access to it. I cannot do much about it, I rather use a workaround. I removed the symlinks and added Alias to the virtualhost config.

```
<VirtualHost *:80 *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName coreshop_demo.local

        DocumentRoot "D:/creation/software developer/projects/2021-coreshop-payment/web"
        <Directory />
                Options Indexes FollowSymlinks MultiViews
                Require all granted
                AllowOverride all
        </Directory>

        Alias "/bundles/pimcoreadmin" "D:/creation/software developer/projects/2021-coreshop-payment/vendor/pimcore/pimcore/bundles/AdminBundle/Resources/public/"

        ErrorLog logs/coreshop_demo.local/error.log
        CustomLog logs/coreshop_demo.local/access.log combined
        LogLevel warn
        
        AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
        AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html
        
        php_value display_errors "Off"
        php_value display_startup_errors "Off"
        php_value log_errors "On"
        
</Virtualhost>
```